# Summing unrelated columns in two tables, then joining based on an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables set up basically like this (extremely lite version):

**Table 1**:

```
ID       Amt 1     Amt 2
-------------------------    
112     $20        $30
112     $50        $60
125     $75        $05
```

**Table 2**:

```
ID       Amt 3     Amt 4
-------------------------
112       $25       $30
125       $40       $60
125      $110      $120
```

All the amount columns needed to be summed separately, the output to be similar to this:

Query results:

```
ID       Amt 1     Amt 2     Amt 3     Amt 4
--------------------------------------------
112     $70        $90       $25       $30
125     $75        $05       $150      $180
```

The joins I've tried result in the records duplicating (and summing) by a factor of the times the ID repeats in the second table. I have no primary key to connect these tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Group the two tables separately based on ID, then join the grouped resultset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any dots (`.`) as placeholders - a regular space will work, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005 or newer, you could use two CTE's (Common Table Expression) to do the summing/grouping per table, and then join the two - something like this:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Amount1 = SUM(Amt1), Amount2 = SUM(Amt2)
    FROM
        dbo.SumTbl1
    GROUP BY
        ID  
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Amount3 = SUM(Amt3), Amount4 = SUM(Amt4)
    FROM
        dbo.SumTbl2
    GROUP BY
        ID  
)
SELECT CTE1.ID, Amount1, Amount2, Amount3, Amount4
FROM CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.ID = CTE2.ID
```

This gives me your desired output

Comment: Hi marc_s, I found this to be the simplest method to use and was very clean as well.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem correctly, you need to do the aggregations separately.  This will work even when both tables have multiple rows for the same id:

```
select id, sum(amt1), sum(amt2), sum(amt3), sum(amt4)
from ((select id, sum(amt1) as amt1, sum(amt2) as amt2, NULL as amt3, NULL as amt4
       from tbl1
       group by id
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL, NULL, sum(amt3), sum(amt4)
       from tbl2
       group by id
      )
     ) t
group by id
```

The above query gives the idea with a `group by`.  Some people prefer a `full outer join` for this purpose:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, amt1, amt2, amt3, amt4
from (select id, sum(amt1) as amt1, sum(amt2) as amt2
       from tbl1
       group by id
      ) t1 full outer join
      (select id, sum(amt3) as amt3, sum(amt4) as amt4
       from tbl2
       group by id
      ) t2
      on t1.id = t2.id
```

The key is that the aggregations have to be done *before* any joins, so you don't have a problem of multiple rows.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff,
Thanks for the reply, I will ultimately go with marc_s since I'm using SQL Server but I will keep this method in mind if I ever switch programs. Thanks!